# Why $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{(k-n)^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

So we know that
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

According to W|A, the following appears to be true:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{(k-n)^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$
(at least it is for $n=1,2,3$)

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the role of the limit in this summation, but my intuition tells me the sum should come out to be $0$. Could someone explain this? (Preferably in laymen's terms though I wouldn't mind a somewhat rigorous explanation.)

Comment: If you replace the index $k$ by $k+n$, then each of the sums indexed by $n$ are the same as your initial one. So, the sequence is constant.

Comment: That makes perfect sense! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling
$$
S_n:=\sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty}\frac1{(k-n)^2}
$$
it should be clear that $S_n=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ for every $n\ge1$.

This holds because (thinking $n\in\Bbb N$ fixed) if $k$ starts from $n+1$, then $k-n$ starts from $1$, hence you're always summing over all the integers $\ge1$.

Hence $(S_n)_{n\ge1}$ is a real sequence, which is constantly $\pi^2/6$.

But we know that given $(a_n)_n\subset\Bbb R$ such that $a_n\equiv\lambda\in\Bbb R$ then $\lim_na_n=\lambda$.

Hence $$\lim_nS_n=\pi^2/6$$

as wanted.